# How to Authorize user on winforms when connecting to telegram

Tags: wtelegramclient

If i run this code on console application:

```
static async Task Main(string[] _)
{
    using var client = new WTelegram.Client();
    var user = await client.LoginUserIfNeeded();
    Console.WriteLine($"We are logged-in as {user.username ?? user.first_name + " " + user.last_name} (id {user.id})");
}
```

It will prompt interactively for  App api_id and api_hash.
How can i Authorize user on winforms application?. So that i can input the api_id and api_hash through textbox

Answer (score 0):

Edit: *(Oct 2022)* Latest version of the library has a [simplified config system](https://github.com/wiz0u/WTelegramClient/blob/master/README.md#alternative-simplified-configuration--login) that makes it more easy to use in WinForms apps.
Please take a look at the [example WinForms app](https://github.com/wiz0u/WTelegramClient/raw/master/Examples/WinForms_app.zip) provided in the repository that demonstrate how to proceed.

The original answer below is still valid but maybe more complex
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

First, you should read [WTelegramClient FAQ #3](https://github.com/wiz0u/WTelegramClient/blob/master/FAQ.md#GUI):

> ##### 3. How to use the library in a WinForms or WPF application
>
> The library should work without a problem in a GUI application.
> The difficulty might be in your Config callback when the user must enter the verification code or password, as you can't use `Console.ReadLine` here.
>
> An easy solution is to call `Interaction.InputBox("Enter verification code")` instead.
> This might require adding a reference *(and `using`)* to the Microsoft.VisualBasic assembly.
>
> A more complex solution requires the use of a `ManualResetEventSlim` that you will wait for in Config callback,
> and when the user has provided the verification_code through your GUI, you "set" the event to release your Config callback so it can return the code.

Here is an example solution for your Form class with a `ManualResetEventSlim` and textboxes:

```cs
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using TL;


        private readonly ManualResetEventSlim _codeReady = new ManualResetEventSlim();
        private WTelegram.Client _client;
        private User _user;

        string Config(string what)
        {
            switch (what)
            {
                case "api_id": return textBoxApiID.Text;
                case "api_hash": return textBoxApiHash.Text;
                case "phone_number": return textBoxPhone.Text;
                case "verification_code":
                    _codeReady.Reset();
                    _codeReady.Wait();
                    return textBoxCode.Text;
                case "password": return Interaction.InputBox("Enter 2FA password");
                default: return null;
            };
        }

        private void textBoxCode_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == '\r') // pressing Return in the textboxCode
            {
                _codeReady.Set();
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }

        private async void buttonLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            buttonLogin.Enabled = false;
            _client = new WTelegram.Client(Config);
            _user = await _client.LoginUserIfNeeded();
            MessageBox.Show("We are now connected as " + _user);
        }

        private async void buttonGetChats_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (_user == null) { MessageBox.Show("You must complete the login first."); return; }
            var chats = await _client.Messages_GetAllChats(null);
            MessageBox.Show(string.Join("\n", chats.chats.Values.Where(c => c.IsActive)));
        }
```